# Ошибка Google Script Aps

Tags: google-apps-script

Пытаюсь реализовать следующую задачу:
нужно выводить 5 первых мероприятий из календаря пользователя.
На моей стороне скрипт работает хорошо, а вот если его запустить на стороне клиента то он выдает ошибку

**Cannot read property 'getEvents' of null**

```
var calendar;
var events;
var str;
var activeSheet;

function onOpen(e) {

  initMenu();

}

function initMenu(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu("МЕРОПРИЯТИЯ");
  menu.addSeparator();
  menu.addItem("КАЛЕНДАРЬ-1", "showEventsCalendar1");
  menu.addSeparator();
  menu.addItem("КАЛЕНДАРЬ-2", "showEventsCalendar2");
  menu.addSeparator();
  menu.addItem("КАЛЕНДАРЬ-3", "showEventsCalendar3");
  menu.addSeparator();
  menu.addToUi();
  
}

var showEventsCalendar1 = function( calendarId = "ldkf5quqq76li9q9efchfo9q74@group.calendar.google.com") {
 
  calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  events = calendar.getEvents(new Date(),new Date("12/31/2021 12:59 PM"));

  str = 'В текущем году осталось ' + events.length + ' мероприятий'
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(str);

  activeSheet.getRange("A3").setValue('Название:');
  activeSheet.getRange("B3").setValue('Дата:');
  
  for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++){
    if(i<5){
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,1).setValue(events[i].getTitle());
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,2).setValue(events[i].getStartTime());
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,3).setValue(events[i].getDescription());
    }
  }
}


var showEventsCalendar2 = function( calendarId = "suh289ad3nb7cvi24hnv8oh2tg@group.calendar.google.com") {
 
  calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  events = calendar.getEvents(new Date(),new Date("12/31/2021 12:59 PM"));

  str = 'В текущем году осталось ' + events.length + ' мероприятий'
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(str);
  
  activeSheet.getRange("A3").setValue('Название:');
  activeSheet.getRange("B3").setValue('Дата:');

  for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++){
    if(i<5){
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,1).setValue(events[i].getTitle());
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,2).setValue(events[i].getStartTime());
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,3).setValue(events[i].getDescription());
    }
  }
}


var showEventsCalendar3 = function( calendarId = "17vd5u8kgha5pupcvequrfdn7s@group.calendar.google.com") {
 
  calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  events = calendar.getEvents(new Date(),new Date("12/31/2021 12:59 PM"));

  str = 'В текущем году осталось ' + events.length + ' мероприятий'
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(str);

  activeSheet.getRange("A3").setValue('Название:');
  activeSheet.getRange("B3").setValue('Дата:');
  
  for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++){
    if(i<5){
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,1).setValue(events[i].getTitle());
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,2).setValue(events[i].getStartTime());
      activeSheet.getRange(4+i,3).setValue(events[i].getDescription());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А у клиента есть доступ к этому календарю?

Comment: да, я открыл доступ ко всем календарям.

Comment: У пользователя нет доступа к календарю. Может быть в браузере активирован мультипользовательский вход и скрипт выполняется от другого пользователя. Пользователь должен попробовать запустить скрипт, войдя в целевой аккаунт в режиме инкогнито.

Comment: в инкогнито тоже не работает, даже когдая я другого пользователя назначаю ВЛАДЕЛЬЦЕМ и то скрипт не работает

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TzdWFrV6kN_3h3eo_TuWmbQC5kwlZDSXAhnHO_j_JmY/edit?usp=sharing
вкладка МЕРОПРИЯТИЯ